# Generate pseudo-random overdispersed Poisson numbers

Tags: random-generation, negative-binomial-distribution

I have multiple sets of data which conform to overdispersed Poisson distributions which I can model with the alternative parameterization of a negative binomial distribution ($\mu$ and $D$ instead of $p$ and $r$).

I am interested in being able to generate pseudo-random numbers from these distributions but cannot find the ICDF to do so.  I also tried to look for how `R` did it but it's buried in the `Cpp` deep enough that I get lost (not a `C++` programmer).

How can I convert a psuedo-random uniform number into a pseudo-random negative binomial number with parameters $\mu$=mean and $D$=dispersion?

**clarification and thanks**

Thank you for the answer and comments pointing me to `rnbinom` in R.  That in combination with `fitdistr` from the `MASS` package do exactly what I want.  **However** my interest is in generating these random numbers in SQL Server without leveraging a .NET language.

That being said, I found the stata code interesting, but it's parameterized for $p$ and $r$ and perhaps I'm just very dense, but I'm not sure how to convert my $\mu$ and $D$ back to $p$ and $r$.

All that being said, I have found a JSTOR article that about negative binomial distributions with the specific application as an overdispersed Poisson.  I'll see if I can conjure a CDF from there.

Comment: Can you either write or give a link to the exact for of the negative binomial you are using? I am unfamiliar with it when parameterized with $\mu$ and $D$.

Comment: Also, not sure if this fact helps but "Negative Binomial Random Variable as a sum of independent Geometric Random Variables"

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use [?rnbinom](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/NegBinomial.html)?

Comment: @gung, how do you specify the overdispersion parameter using `rnbinom()` in `R`

Comment: Also, if you are able to read or interpret STATA code here is a solution: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/code/discrete_rv_v2.htm

Comment: @Dan, from the documentation, I gather you can use `size` to represent the overdispersion parameter & do not specify `prob`.

Comment: @gung, Oh I did to, I just don't know how to do that and was hoping you might ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[R package MASS](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MASS/index.html) provides the function **rnegbin**

From the documentation:

> Description Function to generate random outcomes from a Negative
>   Binomial distribution, with mean mu and variance mu + mu^2/theta.
>   Usage rnegbin(n, mu = n, theta = stop("’theta’ must be specified"))
>   road 131 Arguments n If a scalar, the number of sample values
>   required. If a vector, length(n) is the number required and n is used
>   as the mean vector if mu is not specified. mu The vector of means.
>   Short vectors are recycled. theta Vector of values of the theta
>   parameter. Short vectors are recycled. Details The function uses the
>   representation of the Negative Binomial distribution as a continuous
>   mixture of Poisson distributions with Gamma distributed means. Unlike
>   rnbinom the index can be arbitrary. Value Vector of random Negative
>   Binomial variate values. Side Effects Changes .Random.seed in the
>   usual way.

Sample code:

```
 # Negative Binomials with means fitted(fm) and theta = 4.5
 fm <- glm.nb(Days ~ .,data = quine) dummy <- rnegbin(fitted(fm), theta = 4.5)
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  Base R also has the `rnbinom` function which relates very well to the output from `MASS`'s `fitdistr` which was invaluable for me in estimating the dispersion parameter.